# How can I tell which proxychains config file to use, if i have proxychains.conf and proxychains4.conf

Tags: proxy

[image]

Some people say to edit proxychains.conf OR proxychains4.conf but I have not seen what to do if I have both.

Comment: `/etc/proxychains.conf.save` appears to be a backup of `/etc/proxychains.conf` and it will not be taken into account,  but the latter will.

Answer (score 1):

The [manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man1/proxychains4.1.html) has this to say:

> proxychains looks for config file in following order:
>
> - file listed in environment variable  PROXYCHAINS_CONF_FILE  or  provided  as  a  -f argument to proxychains script or binary.
> - `/proxychains.conf`
> - `$(HOME)/.proxychains/proxychains.conf`
> - `/etc/proxychains.conf`
> - `/etc/proxychains4.conf`
>
> More information is provided in /etc/proxychains4.conf file.

So ... pick one of them  :)

Comment: I would prefer `~/.proxychains/proxychains.conf`(*create it if it doesn't exist*) for ease of use and not needing `sudo` to edit or create.

Comment: you forgot to add "if single user" ;-) Each of these has its use case.

Comment: Indeed I did :D ... I don't use it anyway.